# Can't play audio files on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, audio, windows-media-player

I am trying to play mp3 files on my windows 8 laptop. For some reason they are not being played on any player. I can see the following error in Windows media player:

> Windows Media Player encountered a problem while playing the file.

I am not much tech geek but I checked the sound driver status by visiting "Device manager", it does look fine.

What should I do? Is it a virus attack?

Before, I could able to play audio files. but from past 7 days I am not able to play them. Sometimes the problem is removed when I restart the laptop.

#### Edit:

I tried to restore my laptop at a point before 7 days, but it failed and showed the following message box on restart of laptop in the process of system restore:

[image]

Though the above error, I can now play audio files (*because of system restart as I mentioned before*). Please tell me why this problem happening frequently and when I do restart, the problem disappearing.

Comment: Take a look: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/C00D11B1

Comment: @duDE I did the same on first. It was not useful for me.

Comment: If the problem comes from past 7 days maybe it is reasonable to restore your PC to that point?

Comment: What about other audio players?

Comment: @duDE thanks.. I tried it but failed. please check my updated post.

Comment: @DanielB other players are playing the audio file but with no sound.

Comment: The same here, HTH: http://www.sevenforums.com/music-pictures-video/207651-media-player-opens-but-audio-video-file-won-t-play.html

Comment: In case you haven't already, **back up any important data stored on the disk**. The error code displayed is `0x80070571`, or `ERROR_DISK_CORRUPT`; it might be a disk or file system issue. In fact, the error message box suggests using the built-in disk checking utility. After running `chkdsk /r` from an elevated command prompt, post here the output (it can be found in the system event log). When you're done, perform an extra system check by running this command: `sfc /scannow`. If you're still getting the same issue, consider using the diagnostic tools provided by the disk manufacturer.

Comment: @and31415 The admin has re-installed the sound drivers still the problem persists. According to my observation, if I don't play audio for while when the system starts, the audio driver is failing and if I play any audio spontaneously when the stystem starts, the problem disappears until again I restart the laptop.

Comment: @and31415 and I tried to run `chkdsk /r` in run. the windows just disappears in a blink. and I am not able to find any log file in `windows/system` folder. the folder is empty.

Comment: @Mr_Green Open a [command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8) as administrator, then type or paste `chkdsk %systemdrive% /r` and press Enter to run it.

Comment: @and31415 I can see the following prompt. [image link](http://i.imgur.com/1333FxA.png). What to do?

Comment: @Mr_Green That's normal: the volume is in use because it's where the operating system is stored. Type `y` and press Enter, then restart Windows. The disk check should be performed during the next startup phase.

Comment: @and31415 sorry for late response, I did this thing when I am free. I did checkdsk, which ran for more than 4 hours. Even after that I am still experiencing the same sound issue which is disappearing after once/twice system restart.

Comment: @Mr_Green What's the exact disk model? Do you also get the same issue if you try to play some audio files stored e.g. on a USB flash drive?